# Populate new column from existing columns based on formula

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
nYear   GrpMeanTally   y1
1910        4.1 1915          
1911        7.2 1915        
1912        4.6 1915         
1913        5.6 1915         
1914        2.3 1915        
1915        1.7 1915          
1916        4.2 1915        
1917        5.2 1915         
1918        6.0 1915       
1919        1.9 1915
```

How do I populate y1 column with the value of y1 for each nYear to be the GrpMeanTally value at the previous 5 years. ie y1 for each year = GrpMeanTally at nYear-5

The expected out put for nyear = 1918 will be GrpMeanTally at nyear = 1918 - 5 = 1913 i.e y1 = 5.6

Comment: Can you put the expected output as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on sql server 2012 try this:

```
;WITH t2 as
(select nyear, LAG(GrpMeanTally,5) OVER (ORDER by nyear) lagvalue FROM t)

UPDATE t1 SET y1=t2.lagvalue
FROM t t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.nyear=t1.nyear
```

in 2008 :

```
;WITH t2 as
(select nyear, GrpMeanTally,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by nyear) rowno FROM t),
t3 AS
(SELECT ta.nyear, tb.GrpMeanTally lagvalue FROM t2 ta JOIN t2 tb ON ta.rowno-5=tb.rowno)

UPDATE t1 SET y1=t3.lagvalue
FROM t t1
JOIN t3 ON t3.nyear=t1.nyear
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2008

Comment: Added a solution for 2008

Comment: when I try to run: ;WITH t2 as
(select nyear, GrpMeanTally,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by nyear) rowno FROM t),
t3 AS
(SELECT ta.nyear, tb.GrpMeanTally lagvalue FROM t2 ta JOIN t2 tb ON ta.rowno-5=tb.rowno) IT PUTS A RED LINE AT THE END AND SAYING: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: it's all in one sql block, you need to run it with the update included